# git - Server host key not cached

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty

При попытке запушить изменения в удалённый репозиторий

```
git push origin
```

я получаю такую ошибку:

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Connection abandoned.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Как её можно исправить? Использую git из командной строки в Windows 7.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [git - Server host key not cached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087351/5752652) от участника  [@Rene Terstegen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279573/rene-terstegen).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087351/5752652

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что вопрос был задан в 2011 году, он до сих пор актуален (и я постоянно держал в закладках и пользовался) вне зависимости от используемого движка гит в windows.

Все они под капотом используют набор putty, а конкретно утилиту plink, а она хранит данные о rsa2 ключах сервера в реестре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому можно либо почистить ключи реестра, либо использовать классический способ: запустить утилиту

```
> plink.exe <host>
```

Вывод будет примерно такой:

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 2e:db:b6:22:f7:bd:48:f6:da:72:bf:59:d7:75:d7:4e
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

Затем нажать `y` и выйти нажав Ctrl+C

Способ рабочий, вопрос только в том, чтобы найти именно тот plink который используется именно этой копией git. Я например любил ставить на диск D и указывал переменную среды GIT_SSH, кто-то ставит в стандартный PROGRAM FILES, а вообще plink штука популярная, её очень многие программы тащат с собой (например - sql yog), поэтому важно не промахнуться.