# Git fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@

Tags: windows, git

Пытаюсь запушить изменения в репозиторий, однако получаю ошибку:

```
C:\temp\project1\>git push origin master
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
```

То же самое из visual studio:

```
Opening repositories:
C:\temp\project1\
Undoing none: C:\temp\project1\WebApi\Properties\launchSettings.json
Commit 12ce09fb created locally in repository C:\temp\project1\
Pushing master
Remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas:  42% (3/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas:  57% (4/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas:  71% (5/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas:  85% (6/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7)        
Remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7), completed with 3 local objects.        
Pushing master
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
protocol error: bad line length character: git@
```

Что я делаю не так? Раньше всё работало, разве что недавно перенёс сервер git на другого провайдера, правда вроде все [ключи ssh обновил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1100828/213987)).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8170436/5752652

Answer (score 4):

Эта ошибка сообщает о том, что сервер не ответил пакетом с правильным гит-протоколом (протокол гит первые 4 байта содержит длину строки, поэтому если ответ будет некорректным то получите именно такую ошибку.

Причина же самая банальная: не загружен приватный ssh ключ в putty agent или в Git Extensions.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175315/5752652 от участника  [@Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson).</sub>

Comment: у меня в Git extensions выбранный клиент SSH сменился с OpenSSH на Putty. После того как вернул обратно - ошибка пропала